# Define horizontal resolution

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, screen-resolution, skiasharp, skia

There is a project with .NET 6 target. It is necessary to determine horizontal resolution.

I can do this via `System.Drawing.Common`:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
var horizontalResolution = bitmap.HorizontalResolution;
```

But the requirement says don't use `System.Drawing.Common`.

How can I define resolution via SkiaSharp?

Comment: there is no such API in skia (and therefore neither in skiasharp), https://groups.google.com/a/skia.org/g/bugs/c/DzO6HST5PU8